# Is it possible to remove "Working locally in Scratch pad." warning in Postman 8?

Tags: postman

I have just updated Postman to the latest version and it is very explicitly trying to force me to create an account and use a workspace.

I really don't need any workspace and would like to continue working locally, but I'd rather not see the warning. I don't really see any way of turning it off.

Is it possible to do?

[image]

Comment: I wish I knew a way to add an extension to an Electron based application, or any other way to externally and permanently modify its CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 8.0.3, you can simply click the X to the right of the warning

Comment: That's nice, it seems the update came some hours later after I have asked :)

Comment: Now, if it could NOT reappear every time I open Postman, that would be even nicer. But maybe that requires another update on their part....